# Selenium sendKeys not staying in expected element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to add an xml payload as a string to a text field on a website, using Selenium's sendKeys. My issue is that my code is progressing to the next line before all of my xml string has been entered into the text field. This is what my current test looks like;

```
    @FindBy(id = "macro-param-graph")
    private WebElement graphIdXml;

    public void invokeGraphXmlPayload(String payload) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String myGraph = generateStringFromResource("src/test/resources/testDataResources/" + payload);

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(graphIdXml));
      graphIdXml.sendKeys(myGraph);
      btn_Preview.click();
}
```

I've tried something as simple as trying a Thread.sleep just to see if that helps, but seeing as that happens after Selenium has already done the sendKeys function it hasn't been much help.

I'm not receiving an error message per se, just that the rest of the tests continue to run while the xml string is still being sent, so it just continues while making a mess.

Any help or advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `graphIdXml` is a unique XML selector for the page?

Comment: I've added clarification on what the ```graphIdXml``` is, it's just a id locator for the text box that I'm trying to insert the string into

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a max input length on the input element? How long is your string approx?

Comment: haven't checked for max length, but the field is designed to take large xml, and inputting it manually doesn't cause any issues

Answer (score 0):

Removing the xml formatting of the xml file I was converting to string has resolved this issue.

I think it's a case where it was inputting returns in the string when the file had the default xml format. The code in the question above now works without any edits.